# diff on 2 files in different directories

Tags: powershell, shell, diff

I am trying to apply the `diff` command on two files on different dirs, like this:

```
diff file1 directory/file2
```

and it treats the second as if the relative path to it is the name of the file itself.
is there a way to make it find the actual file?

On top of what I tried adding the -a and --text flags, but my IDE (im using vscode powershell extension) doesn't recognize those.

Comment: diff (gc file1) (gc path/to/file2)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "it treats the second as if the relative path to it is the name of the file itself"? Also, how are you running the command?

Answer (score 3):

In Windows PowerShell, `diff` is an alias for the [`Compare-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object).

`Compare-Object` is designed to compare 2 *collections* - so if you want to compare the contents of two text files, line-by-line, you'll need to read the file contents into memory and pass it to `Compare-Object` as arguments.

To read a text file line-by-line, use `Get-Content`:

```
Compare-Object (Get-Content file1) (Get-Content directory/file2)
```

By default, `Compare-Object` doesn't enforce strict *sequential equality*, so two files with the same set of lines in different order will appear "equal". To get around this, pass an argument of `0` to the `SyncWindow` parameter:

```
Compare-Object (Get-Content file1) (Get-Content directory/file2) -SyncWindow 0
```

Answer (score 1):

as @Mathias R. Jessen commented:

diff (gc file1) (gc path/to/file2)